# Link component hover effect with framer

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I am building a link component with React JS. I want to animate the hover effect using framer motion. The problem I am facing is that when the mouse leaves, I want to stop the animation but only after it completes.

```js
const Link = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const [scope, animate] = useAnimate();
  const textRef = useRef();

  let splitedText = null;

  useEffect(() => {
    splitedText = new SplitType(textRef.current, {
      tagName: "span",
      types: "words, chars",
      wordClass: "",
      charClass: ""
    });
  }, []);

  const staggerMenuItems = stagger(0.1, {
    ease: "easeIn"
  });

  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    animate(
      splitedText.chars,
      {
        opacity: [1, 0.6, 1]
      },
      {
        repeat: Infinity,
        repeatDelay: 0.6,
        duration: 0.5,
        delay: staggerMenuItems
      }
    );
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    //stop the animation after it completes
  };

  return (
    <a
      ref={(el) => {
        textRef.current = el;
        scope.current = el;
      }}
      onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
      className="text-xl text-white"
      {...props}
    >
      {children}
    </a>
  );
};
```